# iTextSharp 7 - Save Dialog

Tags: asp.net, itext

Can anyone tell me how can I create a pdf file using iTextSharp 7 and popup a save dialog instead of saving it to a specific disk location?

My test code is the following:

```
protected void btnPrint_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25f, 20f, 20f, 10f);
            var output = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("MyFirstPDF.pdf"), FileMode.Create);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("test!"));

            doc.Close();
        }
```

Comment: The client pc is in control of the save dialog. You cannot influence it from the server with code.

Comment: @VDWWD In fact you can. My solution below

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found is the following:

After creating the document:

```
string path = "C:\\...";
string fileName = "PdfFile.pdf";

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
Byte[] FileBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);
if (FileBuffer != null)
   {
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
    Response.Flush();
//DELETE FILE AFTER DOWNLOAD
    fileInfo.Delete();
    Response.End();
   }
```